# Is there a better way to dynamically load a viewmodel and view to display a modal than binding the name of the module on app.js?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

What I'm doing feels wonky to me, and I would love to know if there is a better way to do this: I'm using

`<compose view-model.bind="modalModel.viewModel"></compose>`

in my app.html. When I need to display a modal, whatever viewmodel is active will fire off an event-aggregator publish event with a modal model which contains three things. Modal title, an array of buttons (strings), and a module path to a view/viewmodel. In app.js, I'm subscribing to the modal event and when one comes through, I set the app's

`this.modalModel = modalModel;`

which immediately binds and loads the view and viewmodel, then I display the modal (bootstrap modal).  This works, but there are a few problems which tells me that there must be a better way to do it:

1. canDeactivate() and deactivate() are never called on the modal's viewmodel that is loaded, when the app.js's modalModel is reset.
2. I don't think I can pass any parameters into the activate() method in the modal viewmodel.
3. It just feels wonky.

Would there happen to be a better way to dynamically load in a view and viewmodel, bound and everything, in such a way that it can be properly deactivated upon closing the modal?

Relevant Code:

```html
<template>
  <require from="./app-head"></require>
  <require from="./main-nav"></require>

  <!-- actual site content removed for this example -->

  <div class="modal" id="main-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-ajax"></div>
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" click.delegate="modalButtonClick('Cancel')">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">${modalModel.title}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <!-- EMPHASIS HERE: -->
          <compose view-model.bind="modalModel.viewModel"></compose>


        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" repeat.for="button of modalModel.buttons"
            click.delegate="modalButtonClick(button)">
            ${button}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export class App {
  //...

  attached() {
    //...
    this.listen('show-modal', this.displayModal.bind(this));
    this.listen('hide-modal', this.closeModal.bind(this));
    this.listen('show-modal-loader', this.showModalLoader.bind(this));
    this.listen('hide-modal-loader', this.hideModalLoader.bind(this));
  }

  displayModal(modalModel) {
    this.modalModel = modalModel;
    $('#main-modal').modal();
  }

  closeModal() {
    $('#main-modal').modal('hide');
    this.modalModel = null;
  }

  showModalLoader() {
    document.querySelector('#main-modal .modal-ajax').style.display = 'block';
  }

  hideModalLoader() {
    document.querySelector('#main-modal .modal-ajax').style.display = 'none';
  }

  listen(event, fn) {
    this.eventAggregatorSubscriptions.push(this.ea.subscribe(event, fn));
  }
}
```

Comment: `canDeactivate` and `deactivate` are hooks of the Screen Activation Lifecycle; they only work in components that are bound to the router pipeline. Take a look at the aurelia-dialog, it is a specific project for bootstrap modals

Answer (score 1):

Use the aurelia-dialog plugin.

To install: `jspm install aurelia-dialog`

To activate: in `main.js` `configure()`, call `aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-dialog');`

Usage: https://github.com/aurelia/dialog#using-the-plugin